# how to change the format of Calendar object

Tags: java, calendar

I have a string  e.g. Thu May 10 15:48:23 IST 2018. How to convert this string in the form of Calendar object with format 2018-05-10 15:48:23.84.

Comment: You use a `DateTimeFormatter` to parse the `String` to a `LocalDateTime` object and then you use another `DateTimeFormatter` to format that value into another `String`

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thank you for your response. I actually want the end result as Calendar Object with required format, not a string.

Comment: @ABHISHEKSRIVASTAVA 1. `Calendar` is out of date, you shouldn't be using it anymore; 2. `Calendar` (and `Date` and all other "date/time" class) are just containers of a value representing some point in time, they do not have any kind of "formatting" capabilities of their own

Comment: Agree that you should avoid `Calendar` completely and use `java.time`. That said, a `Calendar` cannot have a format in it. Any format you want to have, you can have it only in a `String`. This is also a sound separation between your model/business data and the presentation of the data to a user.

Answer (score 1):

Start by using having a look at [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) and [Parsing and Formatting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/format.html) for more details about how to parse and format date/time values in Java 8+

Based on your examples, something like...

```
String inValue = "Thu May 10 15:48:23 IST 2018";
DateTimeFormatter inFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(inValue, inFormatter);
DateTimeFormatter outFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SS", Locale.ENGLISH);
String outValue = outFormatter.format(ldt);
System.out.println(outValue);
```

Will print `2018-05-10 15:48:23.00`

> Thank you for your response. I actually want the end result as Calendar Object with required format, not a string.

1. `Calendar` is effectively deprecated, you shouldn't be using it anymore.  Even if you're not using Java 8+, you should be using the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) API
2. `Calendar` (and `Date` and all other "date/time" class) are just containers of a value representing some point in time, they do not have any kind of "formatting" capabilities of their own.  This is why the API has formatting classes.  Keep you date/time values represented as appropriate classes until you need to display them, at that point, you should format the value to a `String`